# DOM Attributes and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polymer, web-component

I've been using web components (specifically polymer) for a while, and have recently been trying to get my head around React. I thought there would be quite a few similarities, though I've not seen any way in React to influence the initial state of components based on attributes of the DOM Node that it mounts.

Is this possible, or have I missed the intention for React? Being able to customise components in this manner seems one of the most obvious ways to make reuse easier.

Thanks,

Comment: You would pass information like this on the JavaScript side of things. `ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent whateverAttribute={ some.data } />, document.querySelector('#root'))`. Once you're already inside the React top level component, props / attributes are passed normally.

Comment: Furthermore, it's very unusual when making React components that you would have more than one mounting node--that and HTML is just a markup language so you can't really pass meaningful data from html -> javascript through attributes, like you would when prerendering a polymerized html view. It's more encapsulated in React, which is really nice actually (and of course highly customizable, if you want it to be)

Answer (score 0):

React can access all the attributes of the DOM Node through `this.props`.
You can set the state of a React component so that it reflects the value of the initial attributes like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // here you intialize the state of the component with the value of myAttribute
    this.state = {myAttribute: props.myAttribute};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        The value of myAttribute is: {this.state.myAttribute}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, if you change the attribute of the DOM Node and want to have this change reflected in the state, React gives you a lifecycle method called `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` in which you can update the state like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // here you intialize the state of the component with the value of myAttribute
    this.state = {myAttribute: props.myAttribute};
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // here you update the state with the new value of myAttribute
    this.setState({myAttribute: nextProps.myAttribute});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        The value of myAttribute is: {this.state.myAttribute}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can find a JSFiddle with an example here http://jsfiddle.net/ko2jfqeL/